# using "or" statement when using mongomapper

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I am trying to query MongoMapper with "or" statement. I've found an example of how to do it with mongo directly:

```
db.foo.find( { $or : [ { a : 1 } , { b : 2 } ] } )
```

so I thought the MongoMapper query should be looks like this:

```
Foo.all(:or => [ {:a => 1}, {:b => 2} ])
```

but it doesn't.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want this:

```
Foo.where(:$or => [ {:a => 1}, {:b => 2} ])
```

or this for MongoMapper:

```
Foo.all(:$or => [ {:a => 1}, {:b => 2} ])
```

MongoMapper queries are pretty much a straight transliteration of the queries you'd use in the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 2):

Use: Foo.where(:'$or' => [ {:a=>1}, {:b=>1} ])